# Sum across multiple columns using instructions from a column list stored in a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a pandas dataframe, I'm trying to sum various columns, by row, using a comma list of column names stored in another column as instructions. In the below example, how do I sum the various columns, by row, depending on the list of columns depicted in the 'test_sum_list' column?

Starting data:

```
Class  F12_14  F15_17  F18_20  test_sum_list

A      4       5       6       F12_14
B      35      36      37      F12_14, F15_17
C      66      67      68      F12_14, F15_17, F18_20
```

Expected result:

```
Class  F12_14  F15_17  F18_20  test_sum_list            Total

A      4       5       6       F12_14                   4
B      35      36      37      F12_14, F15_17           71
C      66      67      68      F12_14, F15_17, F18_20   201
```

I tried to feed the 'test_sum_list' column values in as a list to the sum method, using the below methods, with no luck:

joined_data['Total'] = joined_data[joined_data['test_sum_list'].tolist()].sum(axis=1)

joined_data['Total'] = joined_data.apply(lambda row: row[joined_data['test_sum_list'].tolist()].sum(),axis=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Total"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: sum(x[c] for c in x["test_sum_list"].split(", ")), axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Class  F12_14  F15_17  F18_20           test_sum_list  Total
0     A       4       5       6                  F12_14      4
1     B      35      36      37          F12_14, F15_17     71
2     C      66      67      68  F12_14, F15_17, F18_20    201
```

---

Or: If the values in `test_sum_list` are of type `list`:

```py
df["Total"] = df.apply(lambda x: sum(x[c] for c in x["test_sum_list"]), axis=1)
```